# Sweet Alert crash when application is running

Tags: android, sweetalert

I want to use sweet alert for my app so I'm creating a demo based on turtorial. At first I crash into 'android:icon' problem but I managed to fixxed it, now my app crash whenever SweetAlert being used. I have try xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools", tools:replace="android:icon" or downgrade sweet alert to 1.2 version but it still crash. Here are my code.

activity_main.xml

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="add new"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnButton);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new SweetAlertDialog(MainActivity.this).setTitleText("Hello Man!")
                        .setContentText("Welcome").show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: day10.silverboy.sweetalert, PID: 3135
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: cn.pedant.SweetAlert.Rotate3dAnimation error:null
        at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.createAnimationFromXml(OptAnimationLoader.java:77)
        at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.createAnimationFromXml(OptAnimationLoader.java:64)
        at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.createAnimationFromXml(OptAnimationLoader.java:41)
        at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.OptAnimationLoader.loadAnimation(OptAnimationLoader.java:22)
        at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog.<init>(SweetAlertDialog.java:73)
        at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog.<init>(SweetAlertDialog.java:65)
        at day10.silverboy.sweetalert.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:20)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: add you `SweetAlertDialog` class

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your point. Can you explain specific for me what I need to do? It doesn't alert error for me when I adding it into MainActivity so surely there's SweetAlert.

Comment: add the code of your `SweetAlertDialog ` class

Comment: SweetAlertDialog come from pedant dependencies that I compile in Gradle. What and why do I need to add anything?

Comment: And what library that would be?

Comment: @FaizEming All are here to help you. He might have because he thought there might be an error in that and also that you had made that class. Please try to have a positive and polite attitude towards others.

Comment: @FaizEming I could probably tell you why I asked for this class and guild you further. but not with this negative attitude, StackOverflow is not a place for you to get angry on who only try to help you - for the future please come with a positive attitude and be kind to others.

Answer (score 0):

```
SweetAlertDialog pDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(this, 
SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE);
pDialog.getProgressHelper().setBarColor(Color.parseColor("#A5DC86"));
pDialog.setTitleText("Loading");
pDialog.setCancelable(false);

b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           pDialog.show();`enter code here`
        }
    });
```